# Invalid arguements in php

Tags: php, post, mime-types, mime, http-post-vars

When I run a script in Wamp I get the following Warning Notifications for line 17 and 21. What is this telling me and what can/should be done to resolve the issue ?

**Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\eCardScript\ecard_lib.php on **line 17**
**Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\eCardScript\ecard_lib.php on **line 21**

```
<?php
include('htmlMimeMail.php');

function getPostGetVars() {
  global $HTTP_POST_VARS,$HTTP_GET_VARS;
  foreach ($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $value) { // This is Line 17
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
  foreach ($HTTP_GET_VARS as $key => $value) {  // This is Line 21
    global $$key;
    $$key = $value;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use HTTP_*_VARS, they have been [deprecated](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) for years.

Comment: And don't let user input define the names of globals! That creates a right mess which [is why PHP no longer does it for you](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)!

Comment: Yes, you better use just `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$_GET` and `$_POST` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

From PHP 5.0.3 long predefined arrays such HTTP_GET_VARS got disabled by default. For backward compatibility you can enable them in php.ini....

Comment: For backward compatibility you can enable them in php.ini....           is this difficult to do and is it successful?

Comment: @Webiter: Simply DO NOT DO THAT.

Answer (score 1):

`$HTTP_POST_VARS` and `$HTTP_GET_VARS` are deprecated. You should use `$_POST` and `$_GET` respectively.